# Recover Google Cloud Storage object deleted for a bucket without versioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Q1) Is there any possible way to recover a deleted object for a bucket where versioning is not enabled on Google Cloud Platform?

Q2) Since object cannot be directly appended with changes, I read the file contents add the delta to the original file contents and overwrite it. When this overwriting happens, has anybody experienced situation where the file is just removed without appending the new changes? Is it a common occurence?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects), deleting objects cannot be undone. See the [best practices for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#deleting) for more information on how to properly handle your data.

As per files somehow being removed without appending new changes. I think it has never happened that Google mistakenly deleted a file like that, however if you think this is what happened, you create a thread in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to have it investigated.